# Dynamic binding - resolving property name based on column

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding

I have `ListView` with different cells in same column (achieved by using `DataTemplateSelector`). Here is very simplified example:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <l:ResultsSelector x:Key="result1">
            <l:ResultsSelector.TemplateResult>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Result1}"/> <!-- how to make this dynamic? -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </l:ResultsSelector.TemplateResult>
           ...
       </l:ResultsSelector>
   ...
   </ListView.Resources>
   <ListView.View>
       <GridView>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Result1" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource result1}"/>
           <!-- would be nice to use same selector for all columns -->
           <GridViewColumn Header="Result2" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource result2}"/>
           <GridViewColumn Header="Result3" CellTemplateSelector="{StaticResource result3}"/>
           ...
       </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

View-model:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
{
    get { return _items; }
    set
    {
        _items = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public class Item: NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    public string Result1 {get; set;}
    public string Result2 {get; set;}
    public string Result3 {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

**Problem**: `ResultSelector` is the same for all result columns (there are also other columns), the only difference is names of bound properties: for column "Result1" it's `Result1`, `IsResult1`, etc., for "Result2" - `Result2`, `IsResult2`, etc.

**Aim**: I'd like to define selector just once (as I said earlier, this is very simplified version, so copy/paste "result1" selector definition `N` times is pretty bad option, especially if I have to change something later) and use it for all columns somehow.

**Question**: is there a way to organize *dynamic* binding. Under *dynamic* I mean dynamically resolved property name depending on column.

Converter? `UserControl`? Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Would something like

```
public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set { name = value; OnPropertyChanged("name"); }
    }
```

and

```
public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

be a possibility? This way you could at least generate the string and add this as a parameter to the OnPropertyChanged.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem. Look at `TextBlock` in one of selector's template. It's bound to `Result1`, there is no problem with this and it shows correct value. Problem is to avoid creating another selector (defining it in xaml), where same `TextBlock` will be bound to e.g. `Result2`.

Comment: Ah ok, so it´s kind of the opposite I posted. Instead of generic code you would need a generic XAML {Binding Result}?

Comment: Yes, where `Result` value is taken from `Result2` property when it's shown in "Result2" column.