# DataGridRowTemplateColumn - refactoring and using styles efficiently?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I currently have a big lump of XAML that I am struggling to refactor.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CurrentConfigDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionaries/MergedDictionary.xaml" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>

    <DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridRow}}" />
    </DataGrid.ItemContainerStyle>

    <DataGrid.Columns>            

        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Width="25">                
        </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="80" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" > 
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <Label Content="Type" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" />
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                                
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="150" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <Label Content="Version / Date" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" />
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Version}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="150" CanUserResize="False" CanUserSort="False" >
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <Label Content="GUID" />
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" />
                    </DataTemplate.Resources>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GUID}"  />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

How do I pull out the standard "TextBlock" style so it will be automatically picked up? I reference my MergedDictionary at the start, but this doesn't automatically convert the styles in the DataGrid to that of the textBlock unless I manually specify them... which means I need a DataGirdTemplateColumn, and then a Template, etc.

How is best to refactor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work...?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="CurrentConfigDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../ResourceDictionaries/MergedDictionary.xaml" />
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
...
```

Technically, if you create a Style in your Resources, with no Key but with a TargetType, it should be applied automatically to all controls of that type that have no explicit Style set.

```
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Version}"  />
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Comment: This doesn't actually work, for whatever reason.

If I give the Style an x:Key and reference it it does though, which is what I will opt for. Cheers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have different headers and cell templates, I also had [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29699556/1997232) of how to do selective templating. But what you doing  wrong (as for me) is to re-define style in resources for each column.

Why not simply

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type"> 
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>                    
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}"
                       Style={StaticResource TextBlock} />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

You still need to merge dictionary, containing `TextBlock` style, preferably on highest level (`Window` or `UserControl` resources).

Comment: That doesn't completely work... I can't just reference a StaticResource for "TextBlock". 

The TextBlock has no name in the MergedDicitonary so as to override TextBlocks by default. But actually if I define it in DataGrid.Resources as 

<Style x:Key="TextBlockStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}" />

It seems to be referencable.

Which is a little less XAML. Thanks.

Comment: Was going to suggest just that, defining the Style in your Resources, with a Key, and just setting it on each TextBlock using StaticResource. Other than that, technically, if you create a Style in your Resources, with no Key but with a TargetType, it should be applied automatically to all controls of that type that have no explicit Style set.